# How can I communicate between a sandboxed macOS application and a script (or program)

Tags: swift, macos, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I need a way to communicate between a sandboxed application and google chrome's native messaging host. I have tried a Bonjour server and XPC service and had problems with both. (they work as expected if I used them with another sandboxed app, I can communicate between two sandboxed applications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always make a socket-server using python, and send an HTTP request to it from the swift app, and have it send a message to chrome, when receiving the socket.

[The code for a basic socket server in python is](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html):

```
import socket
import sys

def get_constants(prefix):
    """Create a dictionary mapping socket module constants to their names."""
    return dict( (getattr(socket, n), n)
                 for n in dir(socket)
                 if n.startswith(prefix)
                 )

families = get_constants('AF_')
types = get_constants('SOCK_')
protocols = get_constants('IPPROTO_')

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.create_connection(('localhost', 10000))

print >>sys.stderr, 'Family  :', families[sock.family]
print >>sys.stderr, 'Type    :', types[sock.type]
print >>sys.stderr, 'Protocol:', protocols[sock.proto]
print >>sys.stderr

try:
    
    # Send data
    message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'
    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message
    sock.sendall(message)

    amount_received = 0
    amount_expected = len(message)
    
    while amount_received < amount_expected:
        data = sock.recv(16)
        amount_received += len(data)
        print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data

finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

and the server:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the address given on the command line
server_name = sys.argv[1]
server_address = (server_name, 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'client connected:', client_address
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                break
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Comment: " have it send a message to chrome" do you mean two servers ?

Comment: just 1 serer on some localhost port, and have 2 socket client connections to it